# Hide controller in route in Rails application deployed to a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails application deployed in a subdirectory (using Apache and Passenger if that matters). The app is deployed to the /agents subdirectory. Most of the logic of the app is nested within the Agents controller and nested resources under that.

This means that most of the urls are `domain.com/agents/agents/1` or `domain.com/agents/agents/1/clients` and similar.

Is there a way to hide the agents in the controller portion of the routes so that the routes that use this controller would be `domain.com/agents/1` or `domain.com/agents/1/clients` instead?

Comment: Thanks @RockwellRice. That was easier than I thought. I looked through the `rake routes` output and have tried a few links in development and it appears to work.

Comment: Glad that it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the path text using something like this

```
resources :agents, :path => "a"
```

or something. I'm not sure how well it would work with completely removing everything as I have never tried that but give

```
resources :agents, :path => ""
```

a try and see. I'm just not sure if it would cause routing errors further down the file